# Why does Spring Security not prevent POST request for USER role?

Tags: spring-security, spring-data-rest

A Spring `UserDetailsService` contains an `admin` with role `ADMIN` and an `user` with role `USER`:

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsService uds() {
    UserDetails admin = User.builder()
        .username("admin")
        .password(encoder().encode("pwa"))
        .roles("ADMIN")
        .build();
    UserDetails user = User.builder()
        .username("user")
        .password(encoder().encode("pwu"))
        .roles("USER")
        .build();
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(admin, user);
}
```

The repository extends `CrudRepository`

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface CountryRepo extends CrudRepository<Country, Long> { }
```

where POST requests map to the `save` method.

The `SecurityFilterChain` requires POST requests to be sent by clients with `ADMIN` role (see (*)):

```
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain configureSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authCustomizer -> authCustomizer
            .requestMatchers("/api/countries").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/h2").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/countries").hasRole("ADMIN")  // <-- (*)
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .csrf().disable()
        .httpBasic(withDefaults());
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    return http.build();
}
```

`csrf` and `frameOptions` are needed to use the H2 console in the browser.

An admin can create countries with CURL:

```
C:\Users\project>curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u admin:pwa -X POST http://localhost:8080/api/countries -d "{\"countryCode\":\"AUS\"}"
{
  "countryCode" : "AUS",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/countries/4"
    },
    "country" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/countries/4"
    }
  }
}
```

However, so can a user! I expected to get a 401 or 403 HTTP status code here.

```
C:\Users\mahed>curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u user:pwu -X POST http://localhost:8080/api/countries -d "{\"countryCode\":\"CAN\"}"
{
  "countryCode" : "CAN",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/countries/5"
    },
    "country" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/countries/5"
    }
  }
}
```

Why are the POST requests by `user`, who does not have the `ADMIN` role, successful?

Answer (score 0):

The `requestMatcher` matching the POST request needs to be before the general `requestMatcher`. This filter chain works:

```
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain configureSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authCustomizer -> authCustomizer
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/countries").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .requestMatchers("/api/countries").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/h2").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .csrf().disable()
        .httpBasic(withDefaults());
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    return http.build();
}
```